# How can I extract a NSDictionary from an NSDictionary on a lower level

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, plist

I have an NSDictionary that contains an NSDictionary which also contains NSDictionaries. Now I have code to extract what I need when I only have the website. This is my code.

```
NSInteger selectedRow = [self.myTableView selectedRow];
NSString *currentName = [self.theFullArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];

NSMutableArray *theOriginalArray = [self.theDictionary.allKeys mutableCopy];
if ([self.theDictionary.allKeys containsObject:@"#"]) {
    [theOriginalArray removeObject:@"#"];
}
NSMutableArray *sortedKeys = [[theOriginalArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES]]] mutableCopy];
if ([self.theDictionary.allKeys containsObject:@"#"]) {
    [sortedKeys addObject:@"#"];
}
NSArray *theFullDictObjects = sortedKeys;
NSUInteger theFullDictCount = [theFullDictObjects count];
NSDictionary *currentInfo = nil;

int firstI = 0;
while (firstI < theFullDictCount) {
    NSString *currentFullDictObject = [theFullDictObjects objectAtIndex:firstI];
    NSDictionary *theSubDict = [self.theDictionary objectForKey:currentFullDictObject];
    NSArray *theSubDictObjects = [theSubDict allKeys];
    NSUInteger theSubDictCount = [theSubDictObjects count];
    int secondI = 0;
    while (secondI < theSubDictCount) {
        NSString *currentDictObject = [theSubDictObjects objectAtIndex:secondI];
        if ([currentName isEqualToString:currentDictObject]) {
            NSDictionary *theDict = [theSubDict objectForKey:currentDictObject];
            currentInfo = theDict;
            break;
        }
        secondI++;
    }
    if (currentInfo) {
        break;
    }
    firstI++;
}
NSLog(@"currentInfo: %@", currentInfo);
```

Now this works but it's kinda slow when you have really big lists of NSDictionaries. Is there another code to do this more effectively or not.

So let's says I have the value "www.adobe.com" then how can I get

```
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Adobe</string>
            <key>Website</key>
            <string>www.adobe.com</string>
            <key>Sub Category</key>
            <string>Technology</string>
            <key>Category</key>
            <string>Account</string>
            <key>PRLCountry</key>
            <string>Belgium</string>
        </dict>
```

If you look at the image, you can see how the dictionary is build.

[image: The Dictionary image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you specify what's the value you want at the end? I think you are too much extra code. What's the criteria to get only "www.adobe.com" ? And why do you have an extra key which already seems to hold the url value?

Comment: @Larme sorry if I am not fully clear, so I have for example the value @"www.adobe.com", how can i get the dictionary that is underneat it?
You can see what I need abode the picture I added

Comment: `NSString *toSearch = @"www.adobe.com"; NSDictionary *fullDictionary; //From plist for (NSString *aLetterKey in fullDictionary) { NSDictionary *letterDictionary = fullDictionary[aLetterKey]; if (letterDictionary[toSearch]){ return letterDictionary[toSearch];}}`?

Comment: @Larme this is deffinitly a better aproach then mine, I will use this instead but is this an effective way or are there better ways? I think the computer needs to do a lot of work doing like this

Comment: If the website always start with the good letter, meaning that the first letter of the URL (after "www.") is always the one of the keys, you can retrieve it easily and then skip a for loop.

Comment: @Larme yeah I tought of that to, but that's not the case so I guess this is my only option

Comment: Since I see `NSInteger selectedRow = [self.myTableView selectedRow]; NSString *currentName = [self.theFullArray objectAtIndex:selectedRow];` at start, I'm wondering how you got `theFullArray` first, and how you populated the TableView.

Comment: I needed to put everything in one array so i created a function that does output like A, www.adobe.com, B, www.belfius.com etc. This way I was able to create a header like option for my tableview since NSTableView is totally different the UITableView

Comment: What about reading that array instead and which the selected row you do the same?